# Html Print to PDF - Css not applyed if the table split on second page

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

I don't know why when I try to save as PDF the DIV that contains just a simple table, if the table split on second page, the second page don't apply css.

This is wrong the result:
[image]

As you can see, the last row of the table split on the second page and no css is applyed...

Ho to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use media print CSS. Read the following article:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_printing.htm